# Dapper mapping result with primitive type included

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm trying to query a database for a rather small (~80 rows) data set where I need to include a primitive BIT indicating if a `TestPartItem` is the last item of a `TestPart` using the following query:

```
SELECT tpt.[Name] TestPartTypeName,  1 AS split,
tpi.Number, tpi.Header, tpi.Instruction, tpi.Answer, tpi.[Description], 
tpi.Letter, 1 AS split,
tpo.Label, tpo.ImageFileName, 1 AS split,
CASE WHEN 
    (SELECT MAX(TestPartItemID) FROM TestPart_TestPartItem WHERE TestPartID = 1) = tpi.ID 
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) 
END AS IsLastItemInTestPart
FROM TestPart tp
JOIN TestPartType tpt ON tpt.ID = tp.TestPartTypeID
JOIN TestPart_TestPartItem tptpi ON tptpi.TestPartID = tp.ID
JOIN TestPartItem tpi ON tpi.ID = tptpi.TestPartItemID
JOIN TestPartItem_TestPartItemOption tpitpo ON tpitpo.TestPartItemID = tpi.ID
JOIN TestPartItemOption tpo ON tpo.ID = tpitpo.TestPartItemOptionID
WHERE tpi.ID = 1 AND tp.ID = 1
```

While I do know that I could just as well add the bit field on the `TestPartItem` table, it wouldn't work because of the many-to-many relationship between `TestPart`s and `TestPartItem` - a given `TestPartItem` is not nessecarily the last item of all `TestParts`

```
var testPartItemDictionary = new Dictionary<int, TestPartItem>();

TestPartItemAggregate aggregate = new TestPartItemAggregate();

var result = conn.Query<TestPartType, TestPartItem, TestPartItemOption, bool, TestPartItem>(sql, (testPartType, testPartItem, testPartItemOption, IsLastItemInTestPart) =>
                                                                                            {
  TestPartItem tpi;

  if (!testPartItemDictionary.TryGetValue(testPartItem.ID, out tpi))
  {
    tpi = testPartItem;
    aggregate.IsLastInTestPart = IsLastItemInTestPart;
    aggregate.TestPartTypeName = testPartType.Name;

    testPartItemDictionary.Add(testPartItem.ID, tpi);
  }

  tpi.TestPartItemOptions.Add(testPartItemOption);

  return tpi;
}, splitOn: "split").Distinct().ToList();

aggregate.TestPartItem = testPartItemDictionary.Values.First();
```

The object mapping without the `IsLastItemInTestPart` bool works as it should, but when adding the bool, an exception is thrown with the message: "Invalid cast"

Am I simply asking too much from Dapper by combining strongly typed objects with primitives? :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you select 1 as split, split is an int, not a bit.  You have to return CAST(1 AS BIT) AS split if you want that to work. :)